# How do I fix JDK not found error when building Android source?

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, android-source

I am trying to build the [Android source by the steps provided here.](http://source.android.com/source/building-running.html) However I have troubles with my JDK. When launching:

```bash
lunch full-eng
```

I get the following error:

```
/bin/bash: prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Permission denied
/bin/bash: prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Permission denied
/bin/bash: prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Permission denied
/bin/bash: build/core/find-jdk-tools-jar.sh: Permission denied
build/core/config.mk:344: *** Error: could not find jdk tools.jar, please install JDK6, which you can download from java.sun.com.  Stop.    
** Don't have a product spec for: 'full'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?
```

So I tried to install the JDK correctly by the following steps:

---

**Step 1**

Uninstall everything JAVA related by [following these steps.](https://askubuntu.com/a/185250/112583)

**Step 2**

Install correct JAVA by [following these steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/21133/112583). I used the default installer option and version 6, not 7 or 8

**Step 3**

Here I am simply [following this answer.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-building/6KVsiFxpToA/Qgu0cFsxFcAJ)

```bash
sudo gedit .bashrc
```

Edit the file at the bottom by adding those lines

```bash
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle
export JAVA_HOME

# replacing /path/to/androidsdk/ with correct path of course..
export PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/androidsdk/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools

PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME

# Variable ANDROID_JAVA_HOME
ANDROID_JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle
export ANDROID_JAVA_HOME

PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_JAVA_HOME
```

**Step 4**

Test what I've done so far:

```bash
...:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle
...:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
...:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
...:~$ echo $ANDROID_JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle
...:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin:/path/to/androidsdk/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle
```

**Step 5**

Go in terminal to the Android source folder and enter

```bash
source build/envsetup.sh
```

Result:

```bash
including device/asus/grouper/vendorsetup.sh
including device/asus/tilapia/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/armv7-a-neon/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/armv7-a/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mips/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/x86/vendorsetup.sh
including device/lge/mako/vendorsetup.sh
including device/samsung/maguro/vendorsetup.sh
including device/samsung/manta/vendorsetup.sh
including device/samsung_slsi/arndale/vendorsetup.sh
including device/samsung/toroplus/vendorsetup.sh
including device/samsung/toro/vendorsetup.sh
including device/ti/panda/vendorsetup.sh
```

**Step 6**

Go in terminal to the Android source folder and enter

```bash
lunch full-eng
```

Result:

```bash
.../androidsource$ lunch full-eng
/bin/bash: prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Permission denied
/bin/bash: prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Permission denied
/bin/bash: prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: Permission denied
/bin/bash: build/core/find-jdk-tools-jar.sh: Permission denied
build/core/config.mk:344: *** Error: could not find jdk tools.jar, please install JDK6, which you can download from java.sun.com.  Stop.

** Don't have a product spec for: 'full'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?
```

---

What did I do wrong? What is missing? What about the "Permission denied"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

1. For some reason I did not have the respective rights as the "Permission denied" would suggest. Setting the permissions for the Android source folder via chmod did the trick
2. I mistakenly downloaded the latest branch. However I only have a 32 bit system. For 32 bit you can only use Android source that is smaller than Android 2.3 and for those versions you also have to use JDK 5
   http://source.android.com/source/building.html

Answer (score 8):

I had same problem. I got it resolved it my changing the file permission for entire android source code folder:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R ~/Android
```

Comment: It really worked for me. But can you please explain me the meaning of this command?

Answer (score 2):

Also had the same problem but it was due to an NTFS issue as I was not able to execute from the partition. Here is the fix I found.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/164847/cant-compile-in-ntfs-partition

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this is caused by javac is not configured as a alternative for system. So there is no link of /usr/bin/javac for your javac.

Please setup the alternative for javac using the following command:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/javac" 1
```

note: the installed directory of javac for me is "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/", you can change it by your configuration.

Comment: Perfect!! after trying over 25 solutions - this one worked

Answer (score 0):

I also came across with same situation. I activated root user and logged-in and did the same what is mention at http://source.android.com/source/building.html site and it worked flawlessly.